# Unable to copy or paste the cell data of ag-grid while using custom cellEditors

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

we are trying to add copy paste feature to our ag-grid cell.Without using cellEditor for a column we are able to copy value from grid but we require cellEditor for some validation purpose.

Could any one give a solution for where i can use cellEditor and still achieve the copy feature of ag-grid cell.

we are using ag-grid-enterprise 19.1.2 version.

app.component.ts

```
 this.frameworkComponents = {
  numericCellEditor: NumericCellEditorComponent,
  gridheader: GridHeaderComponent
};
```

app.component.html

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
               (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
               [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
               [rowData]="rowData"
               [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
               [suppressMovableColumns]="true"
               [suppressContextMenu]="true"
               [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayNoRowsOrLoadingTemplate"
               [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
               [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
               (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
               [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
               [rowBuffer]="rowBuffer"
               [singleClickEdit]="true"
               [stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus]="true"
               [suppressScrollOnNewData]="true"
               [enableColResize]="true">
```

service.ts

```
        {
           headerName: '%',
           field: 'abc',
           editable(params) {
                              return false;
                             },
           width: this.colwidth,
           cellClass: 'non-editable-color',
           cellClassRules:this.cellclassfornumericdata,
           cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor',
           cellEditorParams:this.getParams.bind(this),
           suppressNavigable(params) {
                                        return true;
                                     },

           }
```

Comment: could you add your code to your question or create a StackBlitz please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to this document:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a minimal code example.